# Can't get last_insert_id from database with Eloquent

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent, last-insert-id

I'm sending data to my controller using a form and AJAX, and I'm trying to return the data inserted into the db to the page.

Everything is working ok, except the id of the item.

The following is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required|max:255',
  ]);

  $tag = new tag;
  $tag->name = $request->name;
  $tag->save();

  $last_insert_id = $tag->id;

  $data = [
      'success' => true,
      'message'=> 'Your AJAX processed correctly',
      'name' => $tag->name,
      'id' => $last_insert_id
    ] ;

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

and the relevant part of the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#submit").click(function() {


    var name = $("#tagName").val();
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $.ajax({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
      type: "post",
      data: "name="+name,
      dataType:'json',
      url: "{{ route('tags.store') }}",
      success:function($data){
        console.log($data);
        $("#msg").html("<div class=\"alert alert-primary my-0\">tag Saved</div>");
        $("msg").toggleClass("invisible")
        $("#msg").fadeOut(2000);
        $("#tagTable").append('<tr><td scope="col" class="text-center align-middle">'+$data[id]+'</td><td scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm my-1">'+name+'</button></td><td scope="col" class="text-center" >0</td></tr>');
      }
    });
  })
})$("#tagTable").append('<tr><td scope="col" class="text-center align-middle">'+id+'</td><td scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm my-1">'+name+'</button></td><td scope="col" class="text-center" >0</td></tr>');
  }
});
```

If I remove the `id` part of the string, it works, and displays the `name`.

The console.log gives the following:

```
{success: true, message: "Your AJAX processed correctly", name: "test2", id: 36}

Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
    at Object.success (tags:102)
    at l (app.js:1)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (app.js:1)
    at E (app.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
```

I'm unsure if it's taking `name` from the form input, or the data being returned from the controller?

Comment: In your callback, `name` is the variable you've defined before the ajax call and not the name in your response.

Comment: Try to replace $data in your js script with data.

Comment: @JCPHPDev - Calling the response `$data` or `data` won't make any difference. It's just a variable name.

Comment: It will make a difference.....data is not the same as $data

Comment: @lewis4u - The OP is consistently using `$data`, so changing all instances to `data` instead won't make any difference. It's like asking the OP to change a variable name from `pancake` to `flapjack`. Having a `$` in front of a variable doesn't have any special meaning in JS.

Comment: FYI changing it didn't make a difference.

Comment: yes you were right...you could write whatever in ajax call instead of $data....it's just a variable name that is used only inside that ajax call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you append to #tagTable you have to use `data.id` because data is json object